# Divs on both sides of main div, filling the remaining spaces

Tags: css, html, background

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around this one.

How would I go about having a fixed width div, margin:auto, and then on both sides of that div have divs that adjusts their width automatically to fill the rest of space?

Thanks
Appreciate any help

Comment: Hello Ben, Please post your html and CSS so that it can be fixed

Comment: What you have to define is a container with a width of 100% of the screen. Inside this container, you will define your three floating left divs or display inline block. Then define %width to these 3 divs and add a min width for your middle div

Answer (score 0):

something like this without any container.

http://jsfiddle.net/JuG8W/

HTML

```
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="middle">middle</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
```

CSS

```
#left{
   float:left;
   width: calc( 50% - 150px );
   background-color:blue;
}
#right{
    float:right;    
    width: calc( 50% - 150px );
    background-color:green;
}
#middle{
   float:left;
   width:300px; 
   margin:0 auto;
   background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7NAR/) it uses simple `display` property to achieve this layout. It gives you consistent layout even if you scale the width to extreme minimum and you don't have to hard code anything except the width of the center `<div>` which you can also specify in `%`.

### Update

First fiddle has center `<div>` width in `%` which makes it good for responsive design. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7NAR/1/) has center's width fixed *(in pixels)*

Comment: isnt the center resizing too?

Comment: Good point :) yes that's because it's specified in `%` which is a good thing for responsive design. Defining center `<div>` width in `px` will make it fixed http://jsfiddle.net/Y7NAR/1/

Comment: well that's what OP asked. fixed center width.

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks!

Also found making the tow divs on the sides' width: 50%, giving them position: absolute and left and right -ing them half the amount of the fixed width div works.

Thanks again!

Comment: yes that's _one of the_ solutions but it'll require you to manage the `width` in multiple CSS classes. Also, if you've content in _side divs_ then you _probably_ are going to have problems with content's placement.